# When to use "their", "his or her", "them", etc. when referring to people in a group

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I'm very confused about how to correctly refer to individuals in a group. For example, which one is correct?

- Today's youth **has** begun to ignore what is happening around **it**
- Today's youth **have** begun to ignore what is happening around **them**
- Today's youth **has** begun to ignore what is happening around **them**

Answer (score 1):

The correct verb to use with a **collective noun** is often confusing. A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself whether your statement is mostly about the individual members of that group, or if it mostly concerns the group as a single entity. Respectively, these uses would take the plural and the singular.

> Today's youth have begun to ignore what is happening around them.
>
> Today's youth is the most technologically knowledgeable generation ever.

Answer (score 1):

The second and third ones sound more natural to me. However, for the sake of consistency, I would go with the second one, "Today's youth **have** begun to ignore what is happening around **them**".

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a tricky subject.

I believe the first is more grammatically correct, however the third is likely more common in speech.

"Youth" is a singular noun, therefore it takes the pronoun "it" and conjugation "has."

For example, "Youth" should be treated the same as "apple":

"The apple *has* not rotted yet. However, *it* does smell bad"

The fact that "youth" in this case refers to a collection as opposed to a single person plays no part.

However, in common practice, you would likely see the last case. The reason for this is that on a case by case basis, when using a pronoun, we cease to refer to "youth" as a unit, and instead refer to them as individuals. For example:

"Today's youth smells bad" --> Here we could replace "Today's youth" with "it".

However,

"Today's youth should shower more often" --> Here we could replace "Today's  youth" with "they".

I would absolutely never say "Today's youth should showers more often", even though "should showers" is the singular conjugation.

Even to my ears, the third sounds the most natural.